# You can't remove design attributes 'helpURL' when the component implements a Lightning Page interface

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, design-attributes, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a managed package. I removed a design attribute "helpURL" from my lightning component. So I get the error message "You can't remove design attributes 'helpURL' when the component implements a Lightning Page interface."

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGUdQAO&title=package-upgrade-fails-with-error-you-can-t-remove-design-attributes-xxxx-when-the-component-implements-a-lightning-page-interface

I saw this post, but I don't understand why this error still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you can't remove a design attribute that previously existed in an older version. This is because it could break existing implementations that depend on this attribute. This is similar to how you cannot delete a global class or an unprotected workflow element. These restrictions prevent the system from breaking as a result of an upgrade. Your only choice here is to document that the attribute is no longer used. Note that the Known Issue you linked referred to a different problem; it occurred upon *upgrade* (e.g. in a subscriber org), not during an *upload* (from the developer org).